# To much errors on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm starting to program in Java, my goal is to program apps for android.
But Android Studio is giving me such a hard time. I already have some experience with C# and I've programm before with Visual and Unity and never encounter so many errors, theres always something with AS. I'm on Win 7 with Android Studio 3.1.4. Started giving error with adb.exe missing, gradle sync error and then haxm, but i was able to resolve those, but now is giving me error with Render problem failed to find style and Couldn't resolve resource, try the solution of change compileSdkVersion 27 targetSdkVersion 27, but didn't work. I haven't done anything, just start the project and is giving that, I let you with the screenshot, Thanks. [This how the error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA3IR.jpg)

Comment: Your question is very very vague. Did you do something write some code or is it giving you errors straight away. Here we ask doubts after trying some stuff before hand.And You should post the stuff you tried.That gives others a better picture of what you want. So we can then help you accordingly. you should go through [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once. I would really like you to make edits and ask again You could include screenshots or just post the errors too

Comment: Sorry for that, let me clarify, Its giving me errors straight away, I just installed yesterday and first was adb.exe missing then gradle error and haxm, anyway I was able to resolve those but now is giving me Render problem failed to find style and Couldn't resolve resource. I found something about change compileSdkVersion 27 targetSdkVersion 27, but didn't resolve it. I just uploaded an image of the problem in the spanish forum. I haven't done anything or haven't write anything <https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193164/android-studio-render-problem-failed-to-find-style>

Answer (score 0):

I just resolve it, so leaving this here if anyone encounters these errors. If you just install Android Studio I recommend you to go to file > settings > Android SDK, then tick the box show package details, install Android 8.1 SDK platform 27 and Sources for Android 27. Hit ok, after finish doubleclick on build.gradle module: app, change the values of to these:
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
The 28 version its giving problems, why? I don't know, but after reading a lot I was able to fix it this way. Especially if you just started with android studio and you installed for the first time.